# mq_send: glibc forces param 2 to be nonnull

Tags: gcc, glibc

My static code analysis has found a bug in my code. I try to send an empty message:

```
mq_send(mqId, 0, 0, 1);
```

It says, the message buffer (parameter 2) should not be 0. It says this because the header says so:

glibc-2.29/rt/mqueue.h

```
/* Add message pointed by MSG_PTR to message queue MQDES.  */
extern int mq_send (mqd_t __mqdes, const char *__msg_ptr, size_t __msg_len,
            unsigned int __msg_prio) __nonnull ((2));
```

glibc-2.29/sys/cdefs.h

```
/* The nonull function attribute allows to mark pointer parameters which
   must not be NULL.  */
#if __GNUC_PREREQ (3,3)
# define __nonnull(params) __attribute__ ((__nonnull__ params))
#else
# define __nonnull(params)
#endif
```

I know how to fix this. I just wonder: is this correctly implemented in glibc?

Neither linux [man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mq_send.3.html) nor the [posix](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mq_send.html) standard says anything about passing a nullpointer. No error code or undefined behavior is described. In fact, when the length is 0, a null pointer is totally valid and works!

Comment: Good question. Ulrich Drepper added this attribute in 2007 (see [this commit](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commitdiff;h=177f96e833c9ebfdef12bd0b513669adbc7283cf)) with no further comment. Seems to be a mistake. I'd say go to libc-alpha (you can send them the trivial patch).